ASP.NET MVC + CastleWindsor: change resolution by header or query string
I have an ASP.NET MVC app running on .NET 4.7.1 that is using Castle Windsor (5.0.0) as its DI container. Since this version of MVC uses a ServiceLocator pattern, I'm wrapping the container inside of a CommonServiceLocator.WindsorAdapter (v1.0.0).
Everything is being set up in my Application_Start() and things are working well.
I have a registration for IDataService that resolves to SqlDataService.
I would like to be able to pass either a query string testData=true or a header X-MYAPP-TESTDATA=TRUE in an http request which causes the container to resolve IDataService as TestDataService, but only for that specific request, its controller and any downstream resolution.
I tried working with the controller factory, checking the request and creating a child container with the appropriate registration changes and using that to create the constructor. However, that only handled injection into the controller and not the downstream services.
I tried creating a custom IDependencyResolver that checked the type and interacted with the HttpContext.Current which sent up alarm bells for me.

You can leverage factory method registrations and named registrations to achieve this.
Here is an example:
container.Register(
    Component.For<IDataService>().UsingFactoryMethod(kernel =>
    {
        var name = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsTestRequest()
            ? "Test"
            : "Default";

        return kernel.Resolve<IDataService>(key: name);
    }),
    Component.For<IDataService>().ImplementedBy<SqlDataService>().LifestyleScoped().Named("Default"),
    Component.For<IDataService>().ImplementedBy<TestDataService>().LifestyleScoped().Named("Test"));

First, we make sure we have the factory registration, since Windsor will try to resolve the first registration by default. This factory registration will make a decision of which implementation to resolve based on the current HttpContext, and return that.
Then, we add the 2 named registrations one for each implementation.
The IsTestRequest here is an extension method that checks for the flag in the query string or in the header of the request:
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    public static bool IsTestRequest(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        return (request.QueryString["testData"]?.EqualsIgnoreCase(bool.TrueString) ?? false) ||
            (request.Headers["X-MYAPP-TESTDATA"]?.EqualsIgnoreCase(bool.TrueString) ?? false);
    }
}

The comparisons here are a bit messy since the AspNet APIs are not as rich as those from AspNetCore, but they should work with any casing and if the flag is present on either the query string or the header. Keep in mind this will fail if you specify the same parameter multiple times. If that's a situation you want to deal with, you'd have to update the code accordingly
Just keep in mind that since we are adding a dependency on HttpContext.Current, this will only work properly when you are injecting in the scope of a request.
With this setup, the factory lambda will execute every time someone requests the IDataService interface, which will then resolve one of the other registrations that are registered with scoped lifetime.
If you want different lifetimes, just configure those for each of the data services and it will be respected by the factory transparently.
